# What is the benefit of building with CMake?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I am working on SFML and I am curious about the option that I can compile it myself. I found it in tutorials, but from the first line I became confused:

> CMake is an open-source meta build system. Instead of building SFML, it builds what builds SFML: Visual Studio solutions ...

1. There is a build option in visual studio too, is there any difference between that build and CMake build?
2. What does it mean that it builds what builds SFML? It means library files?
3. Visual studio solutions? What does it mean? As far as i know, when i open a new project it is within a solution and i can add new projects to this solution (I am confused about why there must be more than one project in a solution too!).

What does it mean that CMake builds a solution? And what is it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake is a wonderful tool for cross-platform development without the hassle of maintaining separate build utilities. On Windows, CMake can create a Visual Studio solution file based on its CMakeLists.txt file. On Linux, generally CMake outputs a makefile. CMake is compatible with many build tools, I recommend reading more of there documentation on their website to gain more information.

Edit: Just to be more clear. CMake literally builds what builds SFML since it creates the Visual Studio solution used to build SFML.

1. A build in VS for a solution is building the library itself. A CMake build generates the VS solution with which you would use to build the library.
2. See 1.
3. A VS solution is the full buildable setup containing 1 or more projects. Solutions can contain multiple projects since VS has a limitation on only 1 output per project. If you want multiple outputs (e.g. 4 dlls) each output needs it's own project.

Comment: It ia confusing , we write a code in an IDE and then we use build and everhthing ia done ! So how SFML is written that it must have cmake to build sloution for it ?

Comment: Please answer my questions one by one if it is possible , i am really confused , i have read that cmake is wonderful , and it output make file , but i have no idea of meaning unfortunately... thanks

Comment: @shayan SFML is written like any other code base would be written. CMake is just a utility to make it simpler to generate a solution. For libraries such as SFML, people generally are downloading the source code of the library and building it themselves. It is a maintenance headache for the developers if they need to include VS 2010, VS 2012, VS 2015 solutions, MinGW build files, and configure/makefiles on Linux with their library so people that DL it can build on whatever system they want with the tools they have available. CMake can generate all of these using it's meta-build file.

Comment: So why we just dont build it with visual studio build feature itself?! And when they build it means they do not compile it as an exe file?! They build a file that you can include ?!

Comment: I think you are confusing CMake build and VS build. Yes, the building of the library is being done in VS. When they say CMake build, this is the generation of the solution to build the library.

Comment: @shayan So the steps are:

CMake Build -> Output of SMFL.sln -> Open sln file in VS -> Build in VS

Comment: I am pretty close to get the idea ! Just one thing remains , and that is i don't open the sln file , i just include the library files . Is this because i haven't compile it myself ?

Comment: @shayan not everyone uses Visual Studio, not even on Windows. It's nice to be able to write one set of build rules in CMake that will work with Visual Studio, Clang, GCC and other compilers on Windows, Linux, Mac and more Operating Systems as well as utilizing build system such as make, ninja and others. Having to write all those many build files by hand would be a pain.

Comment: @shayan: why do you accept an answer, you did not get? And it might be beneficial to improve your typing. Quite annoying to read texts with way to many spaces. Please don't put a space before a dot or question mark.

Answer (score 5):

1. There is sourcecode. People want to compile it. It is difficult and annoying to type the compile commands into a terminal.
2. People invent build systems, to make 1.) more easy. For example make files or what Visual Studio integrates and stores in its files, called solution.
3. There are projects, that are cross-platform. They could provide make files, solution files, files for Xcode, Eclipse and so on. This becomes difficult and annoying.
4. People invent systems, that creates build system to ease 3.). From a common set of files, several different build systems can be steered.

In your actual case: CMake creates the solution file, you can open the solution file and built SFML with that.

Comment: I think this answer is much more complex than the above answer. I am studying c++ for 3 years but honestly i have never encountered any of these concepts and names. Do you think there is something that i have missed to study? And i hope my typing is fine now.;)

Comment: Not easy, rather the essence. Three years of C++, depends on the projects you did. Cross-platform and targeting a range of compiler versions? Or just a fixed combination of a single operating system, IDE and compiler?

Comment: No , fixed compiler, single operating system and IDE and compiler. I want to develope game and i am working on a project for five months.

Comment: Sure, then CMake never made sense for you. Just swallow it, that other projects need meta build systems.

Comment: Ok,thanks, so do you suggest that i must change my environment?! It is better to be master of one or really it worth to change them?!

Comment: Keep your configuration. But to compile and use SFML, you have to use CMake. Once SFML's has been build, stick to your preferred way.